# Trying to create responsive layout but right side div keeps pushing over top of the div on the left

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react component with two columns. On the left side I have a calendar and on the right side I have a section with some text and an input and select field.

Whenever I start to minimize the window the right side elements just push towards the left side until they sit on top of the calendar.

I'm trying to set it up so that the smaller the window gets the content will stay in place and fail gracefully instead of running over top of each other.

[image: Edit blue-bash-32xik]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Col, Row } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import Calendar from "./Calendar";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Row>
          <Col span={12}>
            <Calendar className="myClassname" />
          </Col>
          <Col span={12}>
            Selected Date: <input />
            <TimeSelection>
              Available Times:
              <select size={3}>
                <option>AM</option>
                <option>PM</option>
                <option>ANY</option>
              </select>
            </TimeSelection>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const TimeSelection = styled.div`
  margin-top: 10%;
`;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one kind of Responsive Issue, that calendar size are applied statically.
use below css to fix that Issue.(add css into Calander.css file of bottom)

```
/* make calendar fit to column */ 
.react-datepicker,
.react-datepicker__month-container {
  width: 100%;
}
/* change calendar column width dynamically */ 
.myClassname,
.react-datepicker__day-name,
.react-datepicker__day,
.react-datepicker__time-name {
  width: 12%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your CodeSandbox example it looks like the main issue is that the calendar is taking up a fixed width. The column widths are working as one would expect but the calendar doesn't adjust so that makes it appear like the content is overlapping.

I'm not sure what sort of layout you're going for here but from looking at the [antd documentation on responsive Grid](https://ant.design/components/grid/#components-grid-demo-responsive), you should be able to provide different column spans at different screen sizes. So you could do something like:

```
<Row>
  <Col xs={24} md={12}>
    <Calendar className="myClassname" />
  </Col>
  <Col xs={24} md={12}>
    Selected Date: <input />
    <TimeSelection>
      ...
    </TimeSelection>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Giving each column a span of 24 at the smallest size (`xs`) would make them take up the full width, causing them to stack. Then at the `md` size they're both set to a span of 12 like you have now.